# How to route a chain of endpoints consuming SOAP web service in Camel?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel

Using Camel and trying to create a route where I want to consume a web service where the vendor has implemented several steps.
The vendor wants any client to first call a Login endpoint and then after successful login any other call will succeed.

http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?wsdl

I've been trying several ways but always end up with the return string:

```
<StatusCode>1003</StatusCode><StatusMessage>You need call Login() or LoginAndGetClientId() first</StatusMessage>
```

What I'd like to do is to get files from a directory and then send it as binary(base64) to the web service.

**EDIT:** malformed example, fixed the example…
Here's one version of my code:

```
        final ModelCamelContext camCtx = getContext();
        camCtx.setTracing(true);
        final CxfComponent cxf = new CxfComponent(getContext());
        final CxfEndpoint endLogin = new CxfEndpoint(
                "http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?Login&email=<nnn>&password=<nnn>&clientid=<nnn>",
                cxf);
        endLogin.setServiceClass(EDWSoap.class);
        endLogin.setDataFormat(org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DataFormat.CXF_MESSAGE);
        endLogin.setWsdlURL("http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?wsdl");

        final CxfEndpoint endGetUploadList = new CxfEndpoint(
                "http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?UploadPrivateList&ClientId=<nnn>&flag=ISIN&filename=filename.txt&fs=",
                cxf);
        endGetUploadList.setServiceClass(EDWSoap.class);
        endGetUploadList.setDataFormat(org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DataFormat.CXF_MESSAGE);
        endGetUploadList.setWsdlURL("http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?wsdl");

        from("file:data/inbox").marshal().base64().to(endLogin).to(endGetUploadList).log("MyLogg: ${body}").stop();
```

Here's the trace:

```
2015-12-14 14:38:24:463 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext INFO  - Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://data/inbox]
2015-12-14 14:38:25:513 o.a.c.processor.interceptor.Tracer INFO  - ID-Grevens-MBP-local-50361-1450100301592-0-2 >>> (route2) from(file://data/inbox) --> marshal[org.apache.camel.dataformat.base64.Base64DataFormat@2b289ac9] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-Grevens-MBP-local-50361-1450100301592-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=/Users/mgr/git/FundDecomposition/FundDecomposition/data/inbox/kaka.txt, CamelFileContentType=null, CamelFileLastModified=1449815386000, CamelFileLength=5, CamelFileName=kaka.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=kaka.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=kaka.txt, CamelFileParent=data/inbox, CamelFilePath=data/inbox/kaka.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=kaka.txt}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[kaka.txt]]
2015-12-14 14:38:25:523 o.a.c.processor.interceptor.Tracer INFO  - ID-Grevens-MBP-local-50361-1450100301592-0-2 >>> (route2) marshal[org.apache.camel.dataformat.base64.Base64DataFormat@2b289ac9] --> http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?UploadPrivateList&ClientId=<nnn>&flag=ISIN&filename=gegga.txt&fs= <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-Grevens-MBP-local-50361-1450100301592-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=/Users/mgr/git/FundDecomposition/FundDecomposition/data/inbox/kaka.txt, CamelFileContentType=null, CamelFileLastModified=1449815386000, CamelFileLength=5, CamelFileName=kaka.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=kaka.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=kaka.txt, CamelFileParent=data/inbox, CamelFilePath=data/inbox/kaka.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=kaka.txt}, BodyType:byte[], Body:Z2VnZ2E=
2015-12-14 14:38:25:805 route2 INFO  - MyLogg: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/><soap:Body><GetUniverseXMLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetUniverseXMLResult><XOIException xmlns=""><StatusCode>1003</StatusCode><StatusMessage>You need call Login() or LoginAndGetClientId() first</StatusMessage></XOIException></GetUniverseXMLResult></GetUniverseXMLResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `endGetUploadList` and `endLogin` work as expected, I would try something like this:

```
from("file:data/inbox")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            ProducerTemplate producer=exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
                            producer.requestBody("direct:mock", new Object());

                        }

                    })
                    .marshal()
                    .base64()
                    .to(endGetUploadList)
                    .log("MyLogg: ${body}")
                    .stop();
```

(ProducerTemplate will call you mock route before calling main webservice)

Comment: Thx, but Login is missing, where should I put it in the route?

Comment: Do you get something from "edw.asmx?Login"? Cookie? Apikey?

Comment: No. The reply is muted somehow. We know the account is valid because we can login thru  a web gui.

Comment: If you get nothing from login, then my example is OK. However if you need  to send something back, just get it from the response of producer.requestBody and add it to original exchange